# Is there a Universal Modal Form?, VB .net framework windows forms

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, forms, frameworks

Using VB .NET Framework,  I’m trying to develop an educational windows forms application that will require a child to answer a challenge before allowing to continue normal use of the device (Desktop pc).

I looked for something like a “Universal modal form”, but couldn’t find anything like that. Actually, windows is specifically design to impede user interface blockage by rogue application.

I was able to pause some running processes such as the browsers and media players until the modal form containing the challenge is addressed, but because the device has multiple monitors, the paused applications remain visible and they crash when the child frustratingly clicks on them. Also, game applications from the Microsoft store run in their own sandboxes and I couldn’t find a way to pause them.
Any suggestions?